# First course on scheme theory - opinions and comparisons, what text a novice should use?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

I would like this thread to contain possibly useful information about books and approaches on studying scheme theory for the first time. 
I'm truly sorry if one finds it inapproprite for this site, but from the experience I had with math.stackexchange I think that I've seen more "vague" threads.

Nowadays we have a massive number of introductions to modern algebraic geometry (scheme-theoretic, not complex, though in my humble opinion "algebraic geometry" is a bad name for the study of complex manifolds, "complex analytic geometry" describes the subject better) developed by Grothendieck and his school. I'll list the ones I know:

- Ravi Vakil - "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" (free on his website, very conversational and leaves a lot of stuff to exercises)
- Robin Hartshorne - "Algebraic Geometry" (the classic, but studies only Noetherian schemes and possibly too formal for first times)
- Ulrich Goertz and Torsten Wedhorn - "Algebraic Geometry: Part I: Schemes. With examples and exercises" (600 pages of scheme theory, but no cohomology which is reserved to yet unpublished second volume)
- Joe Harris and David Eisenbud - "Geometry of Schemes" (introductory text on schemes, not a complete course on algebraic geometry, rather a text which tries to develop reader's intuition for studying schemes)
- Kenji Ueno - "Algebraic Geometry 1/2/3" (was published in 1999 by AMS, but apparently not well known by western community as well as by me)
- David Mumford and Tadao Oda - "Algebraic Geometry II" (expanded and updated version of Mumford's famous "Red book", seems neat and friendly)
- Liu Qing - "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (arithmetically flavoured text)
- Alexander Grothendieck and Jean Dieudonne - "Elements of Algebraic Geometry" (the first "book" on algebraic geometry, very abstract and complete, 1800 pages-long, but exists only in French and possibly contains more than an beginner needs to know. But, maybe, even if all 1800 pages are not needed to **learn** scheme theory, they can be helpful to **master** it)

The (not algebraic, mind you) variety of books is definitely a good thing. But it can be daunting for a novice to choose which one to use? For example,

- If one's inclinations lies in category theory and homological algebra/algebraic topology, which books emphasizes the "categorical" and "homological" modern approach? Introducing as much homological algebra as can be useful for the basics of scheme theory? (EGA is a possible candidate, people say it's very abstract)
- If one likes to think about mathematical objects from a "geometric" point of view, which book emphasized geometric intuition and connections with other areas of geometry more? (Eisenbud-Harris could be a candidate along with some course on classical algebraic geometry, as the sole purpose of the former is to help a reader to develop an intuition for abstract machinery)
- Which books is better for a classically-minded reader who is interested mostly in classical algebraic geometry, but wants to understand the modern approach? (possibly, Hartshorne? As he himself says in the preface that he is the classical algebraic geometer, and his books contain a review of classical AG and 2 chapters of applications of the machinery to classical questions, in particular, study of curves and surfaces)

I hope this thread and possible answers could be a useful resource for those starting learning algebraic geometry for the first time.

Comment: You should specify what "studying scheme theory for the first time" means. Self-study? Reading seminar? Graduate class? (If so, which country, and how long?) Will there be another class or seminar or course in algebraic geometry after this one? All these factors are important.

Comment: @potentiallydense I'm not asking "which book I should use". It's just a general thread where those who already familiar with some books on scheme theory can shed some light on them for those studying scheme theory for the first time. For instance, I would like some opinions on books mentioned above or other books not mentioned in my post. For example: "I think Vakil's book is good for those... etc.". Or "a categorically-minded reader would certainly benefit from reading...". Something like that.

Comment: EGA is the answer to all your problems... it is modern up to this day. The other books are written by people who learned scheme theory from EGA, obviously they cannot surpass the master.

Comment: @syzygy It's quite funny, but I heard the author of EGA (and by coincidence the founder of the field) himself say that EGA is "not modern enough". That is, Grothendieck thought that EGA needs to be rewritten using the modern language of derived categories and abstract (categorical) homological algebra. In particular, he wanted to exclude Cech cohomology in favor of his abstract derived functor definition of sheaf cohomology. So EGA may be indeed the most complete reference on basics of scheme theory, but it surely isn't the most modern one.

Comment: Sure, one can say Grothendieck had very "abstract mind" (whatever that means) and the most abstract way isn't the best way to first introduce someone to the material, but I think it would be fair if we at least had one book in accordance with Grothendieck's vision if not out of pedagogical value then at least out of respect for the man.

Comment: @BASIL478 Derived functor cohomology appears in EGA, doesn't it? but yeah with derived functors it would become more modern. But I think a large part of EGA would be unchanged. If you compare vakil's notes to EGA you won't notice a big difference, apart from that EGA is written more elegantly. The modern (derived categories) pov on derived functors is used mainly in Grothendieck duality, which does not appear in EGA. I think saying that EGA is not very modern is inappropriate. If you think EGA is not modern then neither are the other books.

Comment: @syzygy Well, I may be mistaken. I have to say that I didn't read EGA, so what I know about it is hearsay, and I apologize if some of it is simply wrong. However, you sure about derived functor cohomology? My impression was it was abscent from EGA, but I repeat, I may very well be wrong. If it isn't, then I'm glad that EGA is still not outdated. Vakil's notes, for instance, contained derived functor cohomology, though it is introduced after Cech cohomology, as he thinks the reverse order would make the book harder for students.

Comment: @syzygy By the way, the thing that interests me most is how relevant to modern students is all the material in EGA? Well, Vakil's book is 800 pages, while EGA is 1800. Surely it should have a lot of material many of which can be rarely used nowadays (again, I heard Ravi Vakil say that "if it is in EGA, it doesn't mean that it's important", but I may have misunderstood him). That is, how basic EGA is? Would reading it "from cover to cover" be a productive from students of today? After all, it's 1800 pages. As for generality, I think it's one of the pros of EGA, thought many would disagree.

Comment: @BASIL478 Yeah, I just looked it up. In EGA III he defines sheaf cohomology as the derived functor of the global section functor. He uses Cech cohomology for computing the cohomology of P^n, as far as I know there is no other proof (I might very well be mistaken). Well as far as I know nobody reads EGA from cover to cover. You read what you need. The thing is that it is not a textbook, it is a research monograph (nowadays you can find the material in textbooks). When I read EGA (and I do it every day) it is always as follows: a) I don't understand because the statement is too general,

Comment: b) I find a special case which I can appreciate, d) later on I become convinced that Grothendieck was right in using that generality, because applications show the generality to be useful.  I think the section on smoothness in vakil is nothing when compared to EGA IV. Vakil cannot replace EGA, nobody can. There will always be certain (useful, known to experts) statements that you can only find in EGA and not in Hartshorne etc.

Comment: @syzygy Interesting. Thank you for the clarification. Still, the thread is about beginner's **textbook**'s comparison. So, if you claim that EGA is no textbook. But what you said about it actually made me thinking. If it's as modern as Vakil/Hartshorne/Wedhorn, then it's probably **can** be a "textbook" for someone with abstract inclinations and love for generality. Some say that Hartshorne's exercises = EGA's theorems, so mastering EGA may be a good asset for aspiring algebraic geometers, if they are ready to work a lot and work hard, and if they are ready to put a lot of time into it.